# How to prevent sprite kit game from lagging/ensuring smooth movement of nodes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, lag

In my current sprite kit project, every SKScene lags until a rate of 60 fps is reached and this takes a few seconds to do so. In my game play scene, by the time the obstacle nodes move smoothly up the screen via the velocity function and the rate of fps reaches 60, the obstacles collide with the player node and the game is over. How do I prevent this lag and ensure that all nodes operate smoothly from the very start of the game. I would post my code, however it is very long, and I am not quite sure that the lagging is being caused by a specific part in my code. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you